# Locally rebinding `+`

Tags: hy

How to translate this Clojure code to Hy, so it prints 2?
It doesn't need to be like Clojure, i just want to hide `+` and replace it with `-` in local environment.

```clj
(defmacro q [expr]
  `(let ~'[+ (fn [x y] (- x y))]
     ~expr))

(print (q (+ 3 1)))
```

In `Clojure` it prints `2` (let creates a local environment).
In `Hy` it prints `4`.

How to make Hy print `2` also, by replacing the `+` with `-` ?

I need those local environments because i am making a DSL.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you expect in Hy because `+` is a macro, and macro calls take precedence over function calls:

```
(defmacro x [] 1)
(defn x [] 2)
(print (x))   ; => 1
```

Your options are:

1. Instead of `+`, use a name doesn't have the same name as a core macro, like `my+` or `+2`.
2. Only use your new `+` in contexts other than the head of an `Expression` (which is the only place Hy expands macro calls), such as `(map + (range 10))`.
3. In `q`, replace the symbol `+` in the input instead of just setting the variable `+`, as in something like

   ```
   (defmacro q [expr]
     (import hyrule [coll?])
     (defn f [x]
       (cond
         (= x '+)   '-
         (coll? x)  ((type x) (map f x))
         True       x))
     (f expr))

   (print (q (+ 3 1)))
   ```
4. Use `defmacro` to define a new macro named `+`. This is a bad idea because you lose access to the original `+` in this module, including in the expansions of macros you didn't write that expect `+` to have its usual meaning. Local macros are not yet implemented ([#900](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/900)).

Comment: thank you for your time and answer i will try to see those alternatives, its very useful when making DLS's to have this type of local environments to avoid things like `my+` and just use `+` instead.